# Calculate interest reserve and points when they are financed into a loan

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm trying to calculate the total loan amount when financing into the loan an interest reserve and points.  An interest reserve is an amount set aside to cover interest payments for a certain period.  "Points" are merely a fee that is equivalent to a % of the principal amount (so if you're charging 1 point, you could calculate that with $P·0.01$, where $P$ is the principal amount.

If you're financing into the loan amount the interest reserve and the points, both the interest reserve and the points need to increase $P$.  Each subsequent increase necessitates a smaller increase until they become so small it becomes negligible.

To take an example:

- The principal before adding the interest reserve or points, $P_0$, is $58,482.29.
- The interest rate, $I$, is 20% annually.
- Monthly interest can be calculated simply by dividing annual interest by 12.
- The desired interest reserve, $R$, is 6 months.
- The number of points, $T$, is 0.084.

If I'm not mistaken, it's possible to calculate what $P$ should be to the penny by iterating using the following pattern until $P_n-P_{n-1}<0.01$:

- $P_0 +(P_0·\frac{I}{12}·R)+P_0·T=P_1$
- $P_0 +(P_1·\frac{I}{12}·R)+P_1·T=P_2$
- $P_0 +(P_2·\frac{I}{12}·R)+P_2·T=P_3$
- $…$

Following this pattern, it takes 11 iterations until subsequent changes are less than $0.01:

1. $58,482.29 +(58,482.29·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+58,482.29·0.084=69,243.03$
2. $58,482.29 +(69,243.03·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+69,243.03·0.084=71,223.01$
3. $58,482.29 +(71,223.01·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+71,223.01·0.084=71,587.32$
4. $58,482.29 +(71,587.32·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+71,587.32·0.084=71,654.36$
5. $58,482.29 +(71,654.36·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+71,654.36·0.084=71,666.70$
6. $58,482.29 +(71,666.70·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+71,666.70·0.084=71,668.96$
7. $58,482.29 +(71,668.96·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+71,668.96·0.084=71,669.38$
8. $58,482.29 +(71,669.38·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+71,669.38·0.084=71,669.46$
9. $58,482.29 +(71,669.46·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+71,669.46·0.084=71,669.47$
10. $58,482.29 +(71,669.47·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+71,669.47·0.084=71,669.48$
11. $58,482.29 +(71,669.48·\frac{0.2}{12}·6)+71,669.48·0.084=71,669.48$

My question is whether there's a simpler way to do this without all the iteration: is there a formula that's escaping me to calculate this?  When you graph out the change, it seems to follow a $\frac{1}{x}$ type pattern, so it looks like the limit is zero.  That makes me think I'm missing something much easier than what I did above.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406915/calculating-loan-interest-recursively) seems to be of a similar vein, but I couldn't quite puzzle out how to apply the answers there to this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You face a geometric progression. Using $i=\frac I{12}$, the general term write
$$P_n=P_0\frac{ (i R +T)^{n+1}-1}{(i R +T)-1}$$  and you want to know $n$ such that $$\Delta_n= P_{n+1}-P_n\leq \epsilon$$ replacing, this means
$$P_0  (i R +T)^{n+1} \leq \epsilon\implies n >\frac{\log \left(\frac{\epsilon }{P_0}\right)}{\log (iR+T)}-1$$

Using your numbers for $\epsilon=10^{-3}$, this gives $n=9.56$. Computing
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \Delta_n \\
 0 & 10760.7414 \\
 1 & 1979.9764 \\
 2 & 364.3157 \\
 3 & 67.0341 \\
 4 & 12.3343 \\
 5 & 2.26951 \\
 6 & 0.4176 \\
 7 & 0.0768\\
 8 & 0.0141 \\
 9 & 0.0026 \\
 10 & 0.0005\\
 11 & 0.0001
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  It seems that I can use the formula above with an arbitrarily large n (even without calculating it) such that the amount is always accurate to the penny.  My follow-up question would be whether there's a way to do this (perhaps using integrals?) such that you wouldn't need to just plug in an arbitrarily large n.

Comment: I just got the answer to my own question with the obvious realization that that would be the sum of an infinite series, and since r<1, we can use S = a_1 / (1-r), so no need for integrals.